# Recursively find all DateTime objects

Tags: c#, reflection

In my mvc project I put together an action filter that takes the model, traverses the object graph and modifies all of the date time objects. My current code (within the last else block) is throwing a stackoverflow exception.

One of the properties in my model is an EF object with navigation properties and this should be ignoring properties that don't have a value or are a primitive, string, enum etc. Basically any type that doesn't have child properties of datetime.

```
    private void ProcessDateTimeProperties(object obj, ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var t = property.PropertyType;
            if (t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(string) || t == typeof(Enum))
                continue;

            var p = property;
            if (p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                var date = (DateTime)p.GetValue(obj, null);
                date.AddMinutes((int)filterContext.HttpContext.Cache["offset"]);
                p.SetValue(obj, date, null);
            }
            // Same check for nullable DateTime.
            else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>))
            {
                var date = (DateTime?)p.GetValue(obj, null);
                if (!date.HasValue) continue; ;

                date.Value.AddMinutes((int)filterContext.HttpContext.Cache["offset"]);
                p.SetValue(obj, date, null);
            }
            else
            {
                var v = property.GetValue(obj, null);
                if (v != null)
                    ProcessDateTimeProperties(v, filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How deep does the stack get?  If you have a lot of properties it's a possibility. If that's the case, instead of doing it recursive use a while loop with a stack

Comment: I think it would be safe to cut it off at 3 or 4 levels deep. If there's a way to exclude properties that are null, primitives, strings , enums etc then that should take care of the too many levels scenario. Remember this is a view model, and it's not likely that I will have an object with a parameters that has another object 5 levels deep.

Comment: Do you have any cyclic references? `ObjA` references `ObjB` which references `ObjA`. Or even longer cycles like `A->B->C->D->A`. That would definitely give you a stack overflow. It might be worth keeping track of which objects you have already visited so that you don't get stuck in a cycle until you SO.

Comment: Sounds like this is going to get messy real quick :(

Comment: This works: `if (t.Module.ScopeName == "CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary" && (t != typeof(DateTime) && t != typeof(DateTime?)))
                    continue;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is circular reference.

You can solve your problem marking all the complex objects you already checked. like this:

```
private void ProcessDateTimeProperties(object obj, ActionExecutedContext filterContext, HashSet<object> processedObjects = null)
    {
        if (processedObjects == null)
            processedObjects = new HashSet<object>();

        if (processObjects.Contains(obj))
            return;

        processedObjects.Add(obj);

        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var t = property.PropertyType;
            if (t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(string) || t == typeof(Enum))
                continue;

            var p = property;
            if (p.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                var date = (DateTime)p.GetValue(obj, null);
                date.AddMinutes((int)filterContext.HttpContext.Cache["offset"]);
                p.SetValue(obj, date, null);
            }
            // Same check for nullable DateTime.
            else if (p.PropertyType == typeof(Nullable))
            {
                var date = (DateTime?)p.GetValue(obj, null);
                if (!date.HasValue) continue; ;

                date.Value.AddMinutes((int)filterContext.HttpContext.Cache["offset"]);
                p.SetValue(obj, date, null);
            }
            else
            {
                var v = property.GetValue(obj, null);
                if (v != null)
                    ProcessDateTimeProperties(v, filterContext, processedObjects);
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see I'm adding the `processedObjects` optional parameter to the function to mark the objects that were already passed to the recursive function.

When you call the function you don't have to pass this parameter, it will be created inside the function and passed recursively.

Hope this helps.